# "pip install snmpsim " is installed but failed to run the command "snmpsim-command-responder"

Tags: python-3.x, snmp

I am trying to install the `snmpsim` tool and it is installed but failed to run the below command:

```sh
snmpsim-command-responder: command not found
```

**Environment:** centos 7 , Python 3.6

I don't find the command directory https://github.com/etingof/snmpsim/tree/master/snmpsim/commands

I can see only two directories `/data` and `/variation` under `snmpsim` folder.

Can you please let me know if anything is missing here.

Comment: Since likely that you installed 0.4.7 release, the actual command is different, as documented https://github.com/lextudio/snmpsim/blob/v0.4.7/docs/source/quickstart.rst

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem after installing via pip.

I was able to use the below and got the expected response from the simulator;

`snmpsimd.py --data-dir=data --agent-udpv4-endpoint=127.0.0.1:1161`